# AVPlayer playing the last link only in NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I'm trying to play a list of .mp4 links imported from .m3u file, File is save locally in the app and it contains 10 movie titles and links.

Full code

**App Transport Security Settings** Added in **info.plist**

**vController.h**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>
#import <AVKit/AVKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController {
    NSMutableArray *movieTitle;
    NSMutableArray *movieURL;
    NSMutableArray *tempArray;
    NSArray *lines;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *movieTitle;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *movieURL;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSMutableArray *tempArray;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSArray *lines;
```

**vController.m**

```
@synthesize movieURL,movieTitle,tempArray,lines;

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    
    movieURL = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    movieTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    tempArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    
    [self addM3UFile];
}

- (void)addM3UFile {
    NSString *addPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Test" ofType:@"m3u8"];
    
    NSString *fileContents1 = [NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:addPath encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:NULL];
    lines = [fileContents1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
    [tempArray addObjectsFromArray:lines];
        
    [self sortM3UFile];
    
}

- (void)sortM3UFile {
    int i;
    
    for (i=0; i<[tempArray count]; i++) {
        
        NSString *tempTitle = [tempArray objectAtIndex:i];
        
        if ([tempTitle containsString:@"://"]) {
            [movieURL addObject:tempTitle];
        }
        
        if ([tempTitle containsString:@"#EXTINF:-1 ,"]) {
            [movieTitle addObject:tempTitle];
        }
    }
}
```

Code to play the video

```
NSString *url = [movieURL objectAtIndex:9];
NSLog(@"URL: %@", url);
AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
AVPlayerViewController *controller = [[AVPlayerViewController alloc] init];
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
controller.player = player;
[player play];
```

Works fine **ONLY** with the last object in the list

*Links example : http://www.wwwwwwww.com/1234.mp4*

I tested all the links and they all work fine when I enter them in the browser, I also printed each link in the log and they are all there.

I tried to play the links from **NSArray** instead of **NSMutableArray** and it didn't work.

Saved the links in **NSUserDefaults** also didn't work.

When I changed the list order from the .m3u8 file it only played the last link, so now I'm sure that the problem is not within the links.

**one thing worked for me is when I hard encoded the links in the code manually.**

any idea what's going on here ? :)

Comment: Unrelated, but you should keep a `NSDictionary`, or a custom class which will have the url and the title, and use an unique array to have that.

Comment: @Larme Thanks for the advice, definitely will do

Answer (score 0):

After digging more into find out the problem, I finally found the issue.

For some reason when adding urls into the array it added a space after each link except for the last one, I found the problem by counting the string length then logging each character individually.

so I added this lines of code in the **sortM3UFile** and it fixed the problem

```
NSArray *words = [tempTitle componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet :[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
NSString *nospaces = [words componentsJoinedByString:@""];
[movieURL addObject:nospaces];
```

hope that would help someone